# case insensitive name, while preserving capitalization, in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using a name as key, how do we validate the name when registering by ignoring case while still remembering the case when displaying?

In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, setting `config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :name ]` seems  to lowercase the entire name before registering.

Example: some dude names himself TheFourthMusketeer.

- The views will display TheFourthMusketeer, not thefourthmusketeer
- No new user can register under, say, tHEfourthMUSKETEER

Comment: the fourth musketeer is, of course, d'Artagnan :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you might try is to **not** set `:name` as case insensitive, which will properly save the case-sensitive name in the database:

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = []
```

Then, override the `find_first_by_auth_conditions` class method on User to find the user by their name. Note that this code will vary depending on the database (below is using Postgres):

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where("lower(name) = ?", login.downcase).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

Doing this, a `User.find_for_authentication(login: 'thefourthmusketeer')` will properly return the record with a `name` of "TheFourthMusketeer".

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address for an explanation of overriding this method.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. One bug is when multiple users exist with the same letters, e.g. theFourth and TheFourth. I think this is solved  by overriding RegistrationsController#create to check for this case :)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incomplete because it's still case-sensitive on registration. So for example, 'username' and 'USERNAME' could both register successfully, but only the first would be able to login.

Disable case-insensitive keys in `config/initializers/devise.rb` (this can also be model-specific so check there too):

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = []
```

Overwrite the `find_first_by_auth_conditions` method of `models/user.rb`:

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:username)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

...and also set `validates_uniqueness_of` in `models/user.rb`:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false
```

So there you have it: case-insensitive authentication, with case-insensitive registration, that preserves case, in the database.